# What happens to TypeORM abandoned transaction after startTransaction is called

Tags: node.js, transactions, typeorm, rdbms, typeorm-datamapper

I am using **`TypeORM`** as ORM tool for my `node application`.

I have a set of ***statements*** that I need to run in a single ***transaction***. So I am using ***queryRunner*** to manage my ***transaction***.

In my transaction, I get a bunch of ***entities*** and based on some logic I either move forward with my ***transaction*** or return some ***error code***.

What I want know is After my ***`await queryRunner.startTransaction()`*** call and saving some entities, I encountered an ***error condition*** and return with ***some response***, without ***`committing`*** or ***`rollBack`***.

How does ***TypeOrm*** handles it?
Does It just ***rollback*** on its own? (Because if i check logs I cant find ***rollback***).

If not, then what happened to that ***Started Transaction*** and ***uncommitted changes***?

***`I know that finally block will be executed and queryRunner will be released for sure.`***

But what will happen to my uncommitted changes?

```
const queryRunner = await getConnection().createQueryRunner();
try {
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    const t1 = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(T1).findOneOrFail(opts);
    if(!t1) {
       return Response.build(1001, 'not found');
    }
    .
    . //do some update and inserts
    .
    const t2 = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(T2).findOneOrFail(opts);
    if(!t2) {
       return Response.build(1001, 'not found');
    }
    .
    . //do some update and inserts
    .
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
} catch (e) {
     await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
} finally {
     await queryRunner.release();
}
```